# How to display minimized windows in desktop app

Tags: usability, desktop-application

The desktop app can run processes in the background or open property windows of several items. 
In windows the minimized apps are in the taskbar.
If the desktop application doesn't have a taskbar - where would you display these?
Any good examples of how to display?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Webex has the minimize and maximize option in their desktop client. Also, think about the chat windows in GMail - the way they are minimized and maximized.

## Cisco's webex IM:

[image]

## Minimized

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could have a dedicated icon such as (notification) icon with badges. and once any window is minimized we can have an interaction which indicates that the window is minimized and can be accessed back from that icon.
icon can be something like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any examples of existing desktop apps?

Comment: this thing is implemented in a bpm software made by a company in which I am working, I am afraid that I can't disclose the screens as it is confidential.